# Index string array by prefix in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to figure out how to print name of keys and specific sub-sub values from it.
My JSON is:

```json
{
  "results": 3,
  "rows": [
    {
      "hostname1": {
        "tags": [
          "owner:TEAM_A",
          "friendlyname:myhost1",
          "x:abc",
          "y:jkl"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "hostname2": {
        "tags": [
          "friendlyname:myhost2",
          "owner:TEAM_A",
          "x:def",
          "q:jkl"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "hostname3": {
        "tags": [
          "owner:TEAM_A",
          "x:ghi",
          "friendlyname:myhost3",
          "q:jkl"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What I've already achieved is to print just keys of hostnames:

```
jq -r '.rows[] | keys[]' example.json
hostname1
hostname2
hostname3
```

I know how to print key:values from tags array:

```
jq -r .rows[0].hostname1.tags[0,1] example.json
owner:TEAM_A
friendlyname:myhost1
```

But I can't figure out how to print

```
hostname1
          "owner:TEAM_A",
          "friendlyname:myhost1",
hostname2
          "owner:TEAM_A",
          "friendlyname:myhost2",
hostname3
          "owner:TEAM_A",
          "friendlyname:myhost3",
```

Be aware, that the keys in tags array has different order, so I cannot reach it through `.rows[0].hostname1.tags[0,1]` I'm looking for something like `.rows[0].all_keys.tags[owner,friendlyname]`

My bash script was very close, but the order of keys brokes it.

```
hostnames=`jq -r '.rows[] | keys[]' example.json`
count=0
for i in $hostnames
do
   jq -r .rows[$count].$i\.tags[0,1] example.json
   echo $i
   ((count=count+1))
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning `tags` into an object first would make it easier to retrieve tags in a particular order.

```
.rows[][].tags | INDEX(sub(":.*"; "")) | .owner, .friendlyname
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/8_EJ8g-LGhj)</sup>

And it seems like you don't need a shell loop for this task, JQ can do all that and even more on its own.

```
.rows[]
| keys_unsorted[] as $hostname
| .[$hostname].tags
| INDEX(sub(":.*"; ""))
| $hostname, "\t" + (.owner, .friendlyname)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/fhj1F4Iwtb3)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_entries` to convert an object into an array of key-value pairs, then access `.key` and `.value` of its items to your own likings. For instance:

```bash
jq -r '.rows[] | to_entries[] | [.key, .value.tags[0,1]] | join("\n ")'
```

```json
hostname1
  owner:TEAM_A
  friendlyname:myhost1
hostname2
  friendlyname:myhost2
  owner:TEAM_A
hostname3
  owner:TEAM_A
  x:ghi
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/3Hv5RdLm3BB)

Another example:

```bash
jq -r '
  .rows[] | to_entries[] | [.key, (
    .value.tags[] | select(startswith("owner:", "friendlyname:"))
  )] | join("\n ")
'
```

```json
hostname1
  owner:TEAM_A
  friendlyname:myhost1
hostname2
  friendlyname:myhost2
  owner:TEAM_A
hostname3
  owner:TEAM_A
  friendlyname:myhost3
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/UG4S2EGcBkE)